# How can I install the necesarry drivers for my printer without web connection?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, printing, offline

I know a lot of people have similar questions but I looked and did not find any that helped me.

I am running ubuntu and osx on my macbook pro. I have tried to get connected to the internet... I tried ethernet, wifi, downloaded broadcom drivers... nothing worked. I've given up on that for now.

I'll be satisfied if I can print from Ubuntu so now the question is how do I get the driver for my HP ENVY 4500 and then install it in my Ubuntu partition.

I don't know what information you'll need so I can't think of anything else that would help you help me.

Thanks, I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find your driver from this website:

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html

I can't point you to the exact driver, but you can search it trough the wizard.

Once you're done, copy the .run file to your Ubuntu installation, run it, and follow the instructions:

```
chmod +x nameofthefile.run

sudo sh nameofthefile.run
```